# which one to choose, Codejocks Xtreme Toolkit or Xtreme Suite?

Tags: toolkit, suite

I am new in programming and it may look naive to some of you, but I am a little bit curious why Toolkit Pro is needed if Suite Pro exist. Although Toolkit is specificly for MFC, Suite Pro can be also used in VC++ development. If we would like to use VC++ to develop a product, which one is more suitable? If we use MFC in the developing, does it mean Toolkit will be the only choice?

Thanks in advance for your explanation.

Answer (score 1):

I guess they using at different application scenarios. Toolkit Pro for native MFC application, if your application is already developed with VC++ & MFC, use Toolkit Pro can better with your existing applications are combined together. Otherwise you can consider using Suite Pro. I only used Toolkit Pro at MFC application.

Answer (score 0):

Suite Pro is for ActiveX environments, where you can use it in VB 6 (Legacy) or NET language which supports ActiveX objects - such as C#, VB.NET WinForms and using ActiveX.

Toolkit Pro is for native MFC C++ environment.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things that separate the two products is implementation. While some bits of Suite Pro (ActiveX COM) might in fact work in C++, the classes are not always interchangeable.

For example, both products have an evaluation edition on  [Codejock.com](http://codejock.com). Inside the package are sample solutions which show ways to impliment Codejock controls. Looking between versions, usage is different.

Codejock also features usage examples in the [features tour (click features tour to see example)](http://www.codejock.com/products/commandbars/) sections of their product pages on their site- sometimes showing three sets of instructions, for each of MFC, ActiveX and C#.

I would like to note that, if you review the features tours and have JavaScript disabled, you will not see code examples in the non-JS version of the tour.